# gcloud auth login : Properties Parse Error

Tags: authentication, google-compute-engine, gcloud

**i installed google-cloud-sdk in ubuntu 14.04 and when tried to login,it is showing this error.**

krish@jarvis:~$ **gcloud auth login**

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/gcloud/gcloud.py", line 87, in 
    from googlecloudsdk.calliope import base

File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/calliope/base.py", line 8, in 
    from googlecloudsdk.core import log

File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 413, in 
    _log_manager = _LogManager()

File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 195, in **init**
    self.console_formatter = _ConsoleFormatter(sys.stderr)

File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/log.py", line 172, in **init**
    use_color = not properties.VALUES.core.disable_color.GetBool()

File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 782, in GetBool
    value = _GetBoolProperty(self, PropertiesFile.Load(), required)

File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 1141, in Load
    PropertiesFile._PROPERTIES = PropertiesFile(paths)

File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 1160, in **init**
    self.__Load(properties_path)

File "/usr/bin/../lib/google-cloud-sdk/./lib/googlecloudsdk/core/properties.py", line 1174, in __Load
    raise PropertiesParseError(e.message)
googlecloudsdk.core.properties.PropertiesParseError: File contains no section headers.

file: /home/krish/.config/gcloud/properties, line: 1
'h4\xaf\xe3\xda^\xa6\xe8\xb2\xdb`$?\x11\x7f\xce\xc1\x1f\x88\xcd"\x82c\x13Bj\x07\xc3\xe3\x9ds\xdd d\xe1\n'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does look like you have a corruppted gcloud config file `/home/krish/.config/gcloud/properties`. Check what's the context, may be it's just one line and you can fix it, or just move/remove it (you will need to set all configurations once again if you did any).

Comment: To elaborate, the `properties` file is in the standard [INI format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file). From the error here, as Alex suggested, it looks as though this file has been corrupted, since the first line of the file contains what looks to be binary noise.